# Workaround for Making a unique_ptr to a Forward Declared Type

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, forward-declaration

Given that I have a [forward declared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) type:

```
class Foo;
```

I want to make a [`unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) to this type:

```
unique_ptr<Foo> pFoo;
```

This works fine in [visual-studio-2017](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2017) but I can't make it work in [visual-studio-2012](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2012).

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\memory(1150): error C2027: use of undefined type `Foo` (....\src\STETestbed\STETestbed.cpp)
>          O:\Engine\stetestbed\include\STETestbed\ComponentDirector.h(26) : see declaration of `Foo`
>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\memory(1149) : while compiling class template member function `void std::default_delete<_Ty>::operator ()(_Ty *) throw() const`
>          with
>          [
>              _Ty=Foo
>          ]
>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\memory(1444) : see reference to function template instantiation `void std::default_delete<_Ty>::operator ()(_Ty *) throw() const` being compiled
>          with
>          [
>              _Ty=Foo
>          ]
>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\type_traits(743) : see reference to class template instantiation `std::default_delete<_Ty>` being compiled
>          with
>          [
>              _Ty=Foo
>          ]
>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\memory(1281) : see reference to class template instantiation `std::is_empty<_Ty>` being compiled
>          with
>          [
>              _Ty=std::default_delete
>          ]
>          O:\Engine\stetestbed\include\STETestbed\ComponentDirector.h(63) : see reference to class template instantiation `std::unique_ptr<_Ty>` being compiled
>          with
>          [
>              _Ty=Foo
>          ]
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\memory(1151): error C2338: can't delete an incomplete type (....\src\STETestbed\STETestbed.cpp)
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\memory(1152): warning C4150: deletion of pointer to incomplete type `Foo`; no destructor called (....\src\STETestbed\STETestbed.cpp)
>          O:\Engine\stetestbed\include\STETestbed\ComponentDirector.h(26) : see declaration of `Foo`

Was there a workaround for that back in the dark ages, or can I just not forward declare?

Comment: Is `pFoo` a member or a variable? Also, if visual studio 2012s standard library is not C++11 compliant, could you use `boost::scoped_ptr` instead?

Comment: @Artyer `pFoo` is a member. I haven't included Boost in this project, and I think I'd surrender my forward declaration long before I did. VS2012 *does* support `unique_ptr` but yeah, it seems like it is not fully supported.

Comment: Is the destructor of the class containing `pFoo` implemented in the header or in the `.cpp`? (Defaulted/not user-declared counts as "in the header".) If the former is the case, try the latter.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Tried both, neither worked for me :(

Comment: You might try to provide specific Deleter which doesn't requires complete class from declaration.

Comment: @Jarod42 I don't understand what you're suggesting here. It almost sounds like you want me to somehow give my forward declared type a destructor.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<Foo, MyDeleter<Foo>> pFoo;`. I think old `std::default_deleter` declaration requires complete `T` whereas now, only the actual call need complete definition.

Comment: @Jarod42 What should this look like? `template <typename T>void MyDeleter(T& param){ delete param; }`

Comment: `T*` instead of `T&`, but probably split declaration and definition. `delete` requires complete type.

Comment: @Jarod42 I tried this, but I'm getting the error: "error C2207: 'std::_Unique_ptr_base<_Ty,_Dx,_Empty_deleter>::_Mydel' : a member of a class template cannot acquire a function type (..\..\src\STETestbed\ComponentDirector.cpp)" When I declare my `unique_ptr<Foo, decltype(MyDeleter<Foo>)>` Do I need to wrap this in a `function` or something?

Answer (score 0):

[As mentioned by Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57992892/workaround-for-making-a-unique-ptr-to-a-forward-declared-type?noredirect=1#comment102396129_57992892) The problem seems to be that the `default_deleter` implemented by [visual-studio-2012](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2012) required a complete type *on declaration.* Latter versions of [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio) only required the complete type at the point the parenthesis operator is called.

We can work around this by providing a functor which provides a deleter which does not require the complete type on declaration:

```
template <typename T>
void custom_deleter(T* param) {
    delete param;
}
```

To use `custom_deleter` as a template parameter we'll need to make it into a functor otherwise the compiler will error:

> error C2207: `std::_Unique_ptr_base<_Ty,_Dx,_Empty_deleter>::_Mydel` : a member of a class template cannot acquire a function type

So in the header where `Foo` is forward declared we'll need to define the `unique_ptr` as:

```
unique_ptr<Foo, function<void(Foo*)>> pFoo
```

And in the implementation file where `Foo` is defined we'll need to assign it as:

```
pFoo = decltype(pFoo)(new Foo, std::function<void(Foo*)>(custom_deleter<Foo>))
```

Comment: `struct custom_deleter {
template <typename T>
void operator() (T* param) const{
    delete param;
}};` would allow `std::unique_ptr<Foo, custom_deleter> pFoo;` and simply `pFoo = decltype(pFoo)(new Foo);` (that you should probably wrap in `custom_make_unique` anyway).